# Modify the pasting of data (constraining the range)

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am using the below code:

```
Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, 2) = "1" Then

            ' As opposed to selecting the cells, this will copy them directly
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 26)).Copy

            ' As opposed to "Activating" the workbook, and selecting the sheet, this will paste the cells directly
            With Workbooks("Swivel - Master - January 2016.xlsm").Sheets("Swivel")
                erow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                .Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            End With
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    Next I
```

This works as it is suppose to, but I need to constrain the range that is pastes to. When this code is run, it copies the range of A2:Z2 (sample range for this question, it actually copies more rows than this), but it pastes to cells beyond column Z. I am most concerned with column AD as there is code to change the text of that row green when there is a value inserted into that column. After the copy/paste code is run, the row changes to green text, even though there is nothing in AD. Here is the code that changes the text to green in the rows (this code is in the Sheet1 object of the workbook).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'
Dim r As Range
Set r = Target.EntireRow

    If Target.row = 1 Then Exit Sub ' Don't change header color

    If r.Cells(1, "AD").Value <> "" Then
        r.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    Else
        r.Font.ColorIndex = 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, in column AD of a row that we complete the work on, we insert a date and time in this format: 1/4/2016 13:20. Can I change this line:

```
If r.Cells(1, "AD").Value <> "" Then
```

to check for the format rather than the value?

I am still learning VBA, but know that I have a lot to learn. Any assistance is appreciated.

EDIT: The anomaly does not occur until after this code is run (which is located in the target workbook "Swivel"):

```
Sub Remove_Duplicates()
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Z$2000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16), Header:=xlYes
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6

Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This changes the text to the green color, but there is nothing in column AD of that row to trigger the change.

Comment: Sigh. It's not possible for it to paste past column Z? `Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 26)).Copy | .Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial` Anyways, as I asked in your last question, do you need formatting? If not, please use the answer I l linked to.

Comment: @findwindow Yes, I do need formatting for the "completed" rows. This issue is super frustrating, but I know there is a way to resolve this. If the code copies, let's say for an example, 5 rows of data. The code is only copying columns A through Z as it is suppose to. After the data is pasted into the target workbook, is there something I can add that checks columns AA through AE for any null values and clear them out? And this is whether or not the paste action is adding the null values or not. Does that make sense?

Comment: So when does it go past column Z? I don't think anyone can replicate your problem to help you because there's something going on that you don't mention like the last question XD

Comment: @findwindow That may be the case. So, let me try to expand. We will start with a blank workbook for the month of January named "Swivel - Master - January 2016". We import a report into Excel. We will call this workbook "Extract". This report is constantly growing throughout the month. We run the code that copies a range from A2:Z2000 and pastes it into the last row from A2:Z2000 (as needed). Then we use this sheet to input parts of this data into another system. We use columns AA:AE of each row to add notes manually. When we add the date and time into AD, the row should change to green text.

Comment: @findwindow The "Extract" workbook is a temporary use workbook and does not need to be saved.

Comment: Ok so the import likely has null data past column Z. So before you copy the import to Swivel, delete all columns past Z? Edit: still doesn't make sense because you only copy up to column Z but at this point, there's really no way to guess what's going on. Edit2: if you really want to fix it, you need to determine what triggers it to go past Z.

Comment: @findwindow Yeah, I have not been able to determine why it seems to be going past Z. This is the frustrating part.

Comment: Said this before. Qualify your copy range. That's the only thing left to do that I can _see_. Edit: yea debugging sucks. Keep trying to replicate the problem. The moment you do, should be fairly straightforward to solve it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100071/discussion-between-iron-man-and-findwindow).

Comment: @findwindow Was someone acting badly? lol... I appreciate ALL of the time and patience you have given me on this. I have a question (and it may be a stupid one), how do I "Qualify your copy range"?.

Comment: You did it for the paste XD It's the same idea but since it's only one line, just do `book.sheet.range`

Comment: @Fadi. Sorry Fadi, that did not work either. I have edited my question above. You will hate me. I am too close to this problem for my own good. When the copy and paste occurs, the text remains black in the Swivel document. When we run the Remove_Duplicates macro is when the issue occurs. This does not insert anything into column AD, but for some reason the text is changed to green.

Comment: I guess that to fix this, here is what I am looking to do. First we run the extract (copies the data from A:Z (Varying number of rows, in this example we will say there were 5 rows copied) in the Extract workbook to the Swivel workbook. Next we run the Remove_Duplicates code in the Swivel workbook. At this point, we will say that there were already 10 rows of data in the Swivel workbook (A2:AE11), now there is data in A12:Z16. Even though Cells AA12:AE16 appear empty, I want to clear the contents. How can I do this with the varying range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to resolve this in the Worksheet_Change sub, I modified the Remove_Duplicates sub to this:

```
Sub Remove_Duplicates()
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim usedrng As Range

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Z$2000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16), Header:=xlYes

    For Each usedrng In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If usedrng.Value = "" Then
            usedrng.ClearContents
        End If
    Next

Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This has removed the fake empty values that I was contending with effectively. The WorkSheet_Change sub now works as it is written in the initial question above and the worksheet behaves in the manner it should when new rows of data are added, which is that the text should remain black until a date/time entry is made in column AD for that row.

Thanks to all those who offered their assistance. I hope this answer helps others as well.

Answer (score 2):

Since the only question I see you asked here is:

> Can I change this line:  If r.Cells(1, "AD").Value <> "" Then
>
> to check for the format rather than the value?

Here is one way to do it:

```
Me.Cells(Target.Row,30).Activate 'column 30 for AD
If Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.CELL(7)") = "m/d/yyyy h:mm;@" Then
```

Adjust your formatting as *exactly* needed. I only guessed based on the information in your question.

Comment: I changed the code with your suggestion above and received a RT '1004' error (Activate method of Range class failed) and pointed to 'r.Cells(1, "AD").Activate'.

Comment: Ok. Now I get a RT '13' - Type mismatch pointing to 'Me.Cells(r,"AD").Activate' What does 'Me.Cells' do?

Comment: sorry - I am out of it today. See my edit again. With the `Cells` method, you need the row and column *number*, not letter. `Me` refers to the Worksheet Object (inside of worksheet event code). `Cells` just references a cell by row and column.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for assisting. I made the latest changes as per your edit and still get a RT '13' - Type mismatch pointing to 'Me.Cells(r, 30).Activate'

Comment: Okay. Hopefully, last edit. `R.Row`. I thought r was already the row number originally.

Comment: Sorry. Now we are back to this error - RT '1004' error (Activate method of Range class failed) and pointed to 'Me.Cells(r.row, 30).Activate'

Comment: Change `r.Row` to `Target.row`

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner - I need the extra help today! I think maybe I should have just stayed at home today :(

Comment: Sometimes it just takes a pair of fresh eyes.

Comment: @ScottCraner Ha ha - Well, we may need another set :p. I made the suggested change and got this: RT '1004' error (Activate method of Range class failed) and pointed to 'Me.Cells(Target.row, 30).Activate'.

Comment: @IronMan is your sheet protected?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I got this to work if I removed the `;@` from the format string.  Other wise it never registered as true.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @ScottCraner No, there is no protection on the workbook at all. I tried removing the ;@ also but received the same RT 1004 error.

Comment: @IronMan, How about; do you have a Worksheet_SelectionChange event on the worksheet that may be interrupting?  I got the code to work without a hitch, so I am trying to figure out why yours is not.

Comment: One thing that I just real is that even though I am receiving these errors, one row is being copied over to the Swivel workbook and the text is black (this is the almost the desired result), but the error occurs and does not copy over all the rows (in this case there are 21 rows A2:Z22). Keep in mind that this range (number of rows) varies each time we run this. Hope this helps a little.

Comment: @ScottCraner Just the Worksheet_Change we are currently working on from the question above. There are no other sub's in the Worksheet object.

Comment: So, let's say that we run the Extract and this copies data into cells A10:Z22. Then we run the remove duplicates, but there are none (for this example). How could we then remove the contents of AA:AE of JUST the rows that were copied over? Or that would remain if there were, let's say, 2 duplicates.

Comment: @ScottCraner - That is interesting. Because when I did a debug.print on with the `GET.Cell(7)` the format printed out with the `;@` at the end. But as we know, sometimes what prints out isn't always how the live code works :)

Comment: @IronMan - it seems like you are asking a question unrelated to the answer here about finding only cells with a certain format. It seems the copying and pasting and removing duplicates is a separate issue. Therefore, it's confusing to try to help on **all** the issues in one post.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I agree. While my question above was specific to the format of certain cells, this is part of another issue (which I do have the question still open here in SO). This is a complicated one. I will say this, The information you have provided is leading me in the right direction and I am trying other variations while we are discussing this. All of your assistance is very much appreciated.

Comment: Actually, I was asking a variation of the initial question since we still do not have an answer to the posted question. Just trying to attack this from all angles as I am still learning VBA. Not trying to break SO protocol. :)

Comment: Are we now recommending the [Range .Activate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221681(v=office.11).aspx) and subsequent reliance on the [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx)? To quote Coach Lou Brown from Major League, *'We wear shirts with sleeves at this level son.'*.

Comment: Not recommending in general @Jeeped. But in this case, I couldn't find a way for the Excel4Macro to execute on the desired cell without activating it first. If you have a better way, by all means, please let us know :)

Comment: The VBA [Range.NumberFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx) would seem to be similar. `If Me.Cells(Target.Row,30).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm;@" Then`

Comment: @Jeeped . I tried that at first, but it didn't seem to work, right. Perhaps I did not test it enough or was not thinking properly (which happened *a lot* yesterday!)